# Can I learn Dual Talent Specialization?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

World of Warcraft has an ability to have two different talent builds and switch between them with a button press.

Does this exist in Star Wars: The Old Republic?  If so, where (and when) do I learn it and how much does it cost to learn?

Comment: To elaborate on this, I'm playing a Sith Sorcerer, and I'd *really* like the ability to switch between Healing build and Lightning build.

Answer (score 10):

No.  As of right now there is no way to maintain more than one talent specialization at a time.

However, respeccing is free for subscribers and the cost to respec resets weekly for others.  There is also a purchasable Legacy perk allowing you to respec anywhere rather than just at the skill mentor.